# Every second image I capture using CameraX is an invalid Green background image

Tags: android, android-camerax

[image]I was trying out the new CameraX api to simply take images and every 2nd image(like 1st one is fine, 2nd one is not, 3rd fine, 4th is not) is turning out to be a green background (please see the image above)

```
private void startCamera() {
    CameraX.unbindAll();

    int aspRatioW = textureView.getWidth(); 
    int aspRatioH = textureView.getHeight(); 
    Rational asp = new Rational (aspRatioW, aspRatioH); 

    PreviewConfig previewConfig=new PreviewConfig.Builder()
            .setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            .build();

    preview=new Preview(previewConfig);


    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup=(ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
            viewGroup.removeView(textureView);
            viewGroup.addView(textureView, 0);

            textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
            updateTransform();
        }
    });

    ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig=new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
            .setTargetAspectRatio(asp)
            .build();
    final ImageCapture imgCap=new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

    findViewById(R.id.camera_photoButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"Prixpi_"+System.currentTimeMillis()
                    +".jpg");
            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
                    ScanImagePath obj=new ScanImagePath(path);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onImageSaved: path="+obj.getImagePath());
                    mRepo.insertImageTask(obj);
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Image captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null){
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, imgCap, preview);
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated

Comment: The library is in alpha stage right now. It will have issues. If you have followed the integration docs and still facing this problem, you should file the bug report with Google.

Comment: apparently it was an issue that persisted only for my phone